# problem with non-ASCII characters in Url in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, non-ascii-characters

I write a MVC 3 application with 2 languages: en and fa; and to optimize Url's for search-engines, I use page's title in Urls, like this (for one page in 2 lang):

```
mysite.com/en/Home/Sheet/2/my-presentation-page
mysite.com/fa/Home/Sheet/2/صفحه-معرفی-من
```

and the route map is:

```
{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{uriTitle}
```

In local, that does work, but when I upload it on internet, the first Url works correctly, but the second, only shows home-page!!! (mysite.com/fa/Home/Index) without any redirecting or throwing any error!!! just, shows the above Url's content!!! 
Notice that the Url doesn't changes! just the content is the home-page's content! just it!
Help me please, I don't understand WHY??????
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer myself. MVC doesn't had any problem! My problem was this:
The server, reject all requests with non-ASCII characters in their url!!! In fact, the web-server, when receive a request that contains non-ascii chars, response it with the cached-default page of site, instead of pass the request to application! 
I change my hosting company and my problem resolved.
Thanks to all, Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is still problematic.  The official specification for URL syntax explicitly states that characters outside of the US-ASCII range should be percent-encoded, so your old hosting company's implementation had it correct.  Furthermore, if your new host does not follow this standard, then there is a chance you are exposing security vulnerabilities via injection.

> The ABNF notation defines its terminal values to be non-negative
>    integers (codepoints) based on the US-ASCII coded character set
>    [ASCII].  Because a URI is a sequence of characters, we must invert
>    that relation in order to understand the URI syntax.  Therefore, the
>    integer values used by the ABNF must be mapped back to their
>    corresponding characters via US-ASCII in order to complete the syntax
>    rules.
>
> A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of
> digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols.  A reserved subset of
> those characters may be used to delimit syntax components within a
> URI while the remaining characters, including both the unreserved set
> and those reserved characters not acting as delimiters, define each
> component's identifying data.

The ABNF syntax for valid URLs is located at : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A